# How to add the data in the next page if the content in the html table exceeds some rows?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to development. I have a page which looks like here below.

[image]

I want the below functionality to work. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Here below is my code for the above picture to show the table with list of users and edit, delete button and below buttons for navigating to the next page. I want to make if the rows are 6 it should automatically go to the next page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap CRUD Data Table for Database with Modal Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/weblayout/tablestyle.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     // Activate tooltip
     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
     
     // Select/Deselect checkboxes
     var checkbox = $('table tbody input[type="checkbox"]');
     $("#selectAll").click(function(){
      if(this.checked){
       checkbox.each(function(){
        this.checked = true;                        
       });
      } else{
       checkbox.each(function(){
        this.checked = false;                        
       });
      } 
     });
     checkbox.click(function(){
      if(!this.checked){
       $("#selectAll").prop("checked", false);
      }
     });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="table-wrapper">
                <div class="table-title">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h2>Manage <b>Employees</b></h2>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
          <a href="#addEmployeeModal" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons">&#xE147;</i> <span>Add New Employee</span></a>
          <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons">&#xE15C;</i> <span>Delete</span></a>      
         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
          <th>
           <span class="custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
            <label for="selectAll"></label>
           </span>
          </th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
          <th>Address</th>
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
          <td>
           <span class="custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="options[]" value="1">
            <label for="checkbox1"></label>
           </span>
          </td>
                            <td>Thomas Hardy</td>
                            <td>thomashardy@mail.com</td>
          <td>89 Chiaroscuro Rd, Portland, USA</td>
                            <td>(171) 555-2222</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                                <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
          <td>
           <span class="custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="options[]" value="1">
            <label for="checkbox2"></label>
           </span>
          </td>
                            <td>Dominique Perrier</td>
                            <td>dominiqueperrier@mail.com</td>
          <td>Obere Str. 57, Berlin, Germany</td>
                            <td>(313) 555-5735</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                                <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>
           <span class="custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" name="options[]" value="1">
            <label for="checkbox3"></label>
           </span>
          </td>
                            <td>Maria Anders</td>
                            <td>mariaanders@mail.com</td>
          <td>25, rue Lauriston, Paris, France</td>
                            <td>(503) 555-9931</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                                <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
          <td>
           <span class="custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" name="options[]" value="1">
            <label for="checkbox4"></label>
           </span>
          </td>
                            <td>Fran Wilson</td>
                            <td>franwilson@mail.com</td>
          <td>C/ Araquil, 67, Madrid, Spain</td>
                            <td>(204) 619-5731</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                                <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>     
         <tr>
          <td>
           <span class="custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox5" name="options[]" value="1">
            <label for="checkbox5"></label>
           </span>
          </td>
                            <td>Martin Blank</td>
                            <td>martinblank@mail.com</td>
          <td>Via Monte Bianco 34, Turin, Italy</td>
                            <td>(480) 631-2097</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                                <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr> 
                    </tbody>
                </table>
       <div class="clearfix">
                    <div class="hint-text">Showing <b>5</b> out of <b>25</b> entries</div>
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        <li class="page-item disabled"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">1</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">2</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item active"><a href="#" class="page-link">3</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">4</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">5</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">Next</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     <!-- Edit Modal HTML -->
     <div id="addEmployeeModal" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
        <form>
         <div class="modal-header">      
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add Employee</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">     
          <div class="form-group">
           <label>Name</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
           <label>Email</label>
           <input type="email" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
           <label>Address</label>
           <textarea class="form-control" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
           <label>Phone</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
          </div>     
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add">
         </div>
        </form>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <!-- Edit Modal HTML -->
     <div id="editEmployeeModal" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
        <form>
         <div class="modal-header">      
          <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Employee</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">     
          <div class="form-group">
           <label>Name</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
           <label>Email</label>
           <input type="email" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
           <label>Address</label>
           <textarea class="form-control" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
           <label>Phone</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
          </div>     
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Save">
         </div>
        </form>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <!-- Delete Modal HTML -->
     <div id="deleteEmployeeModal" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
        <form>
         <div class="modal-header">      
          <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Employee</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">     
          <p>Are you sure you want to delete these Records?</p>
          <p class="text-warning"><small>This action cannot be undone.</small></p>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
         </div>
        </form>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question does not have a specific problem for us to solve, thus it's too broad. Can you narrow it down to a specific problem you are facing in ***your implementation*** by adding a [mcve]?

Comment: I have added my code @Esko

Comment: This won't work with hard coded data. How are you retrieving your table data? You need to keep track of the `pageNum` and `maxPerPage` to slice your data array into pages.